# Simple, explicit, functorial cylinder object in CDGA

Tags: homological-algebra, model-categories, differential-graded-algebras

In the model category of graded commutative dg-algebras CDGA over $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the projective model structure) there is a simple, functorial construction of a path object given by tensoring with the dga of polynomial differential forms on the interval. This construction comes from the simplicial model category structure on CDGA.

Is there is a similar, explicit construction of a *cylinder* object? If so, what is a good reference?

Comment: There is a cylinder construction for dg categories here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.03411. I guess one should decategorify and commutify it...